# WinForms ObjectListView Select all checkbox in header not working

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView 2.9.1.1072 to create a list with a checkbox on each row. For the first column I have HeaderCheckbox and HeaderCheckboxUpdatesRowCheckboxes set to true. However, when I click the checkbox in the column header, it is not checking/unchecking all the items in my list as it should be (in fact it is not doing anything at all). Am I missing something? The documentation is sketchy at best and the cookbook page on the website is not very helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed just by adding a public override int GetHashCode() and Equals() methods to my model class (the latter using GetHashCode to resolve equality of the two objects). ObjectViewList appears to use these methods to maintain checked status on the list items. Would have been nice if the docs made this a little clearer. If either of these are missing, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Do you have a base class for your model? GetHashCode / Equality is NOT required for `HeaderCheckBox` / `HeaderCheckBoxUpdatesRowCheckBoxes` since the default implementation on System.Object will work.  You can break it by creating a flawed GetHashCode implementation (e.g. return a random number).  The only other time I've seen where you definetly want to implement equality is if you are making changes to the collection of objects behind the scenes (e.g. in the checked handler) where new instances are comming in (e.g. from the database) where you consider it the same object but olv/c# doesn't.